# I would like to exclude some rows by Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a user table that contains a colum "role"
i would like to exclude the ones that contains a certain role by Eloquent
Does any one knows a solution for this ?

Comment: Show us the query you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original comment

```
User::query()->whereNotIn('role', 'blabla')->get();
```

To answer the second edit of the comment:

```
User::query()->whereNotIn('role', [
    'Admin', 'responsable', 'magasinier', 'demandeur' 
])->get();
```

To answer the third edit of the comment:

```
User::query()->whereNotIn('role', 'demandeur')->get();
```

Comment: i actually have 4 roles : Admin, responsable,magasinier and demandeur and i would like to exclude the demandeur role

Comment: @Zen3x All edits of the above question is sufficient for you to use the solution.